Docker DIND give non-root access to docker.sock
There are existing questions and answers on the topic but these are no longer applicable. The solution outlined here is broken because /var/run/docker.sock does not exist at container runtime. Mounting /var/run/docker.sock results in a directory being created instead and dind failing to start. Forcing a bind mount results in an error for the same reason, nonexistent docker.sock.
Mounting /var/run instead, works. However the socket belongs to root:root and cannot be accessed from a non-root container (results in a standard Docker permission denied error). This also means that the gid change fix does not work because I can't read the dind docker group gid from inside the myapp container. The application container runs as root so I can run scripts as root in the docker-entrypoint.sh to change socket permissions but the application itself that needs dind access is run as a non-root user using su-exec.
docker-compose.yml snippet:
---
  myapp-docker:
    # image: mycorp/myapp-docker:dind-rootless # this was an attempt at running dind-rootless image which also failed
    image: docker:20.10.17-dind
    container_name: myapp-docker
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/docker/run:/var/run/
      - ./data/docker/lib:/var/lib/docker
      - ./data/docker/certs:/certs
    environment:
      DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: /certs
    networks:
      myappnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.7

I have mounted ./data/docker/run and ./data/docker/lib in the myapp container.
An alternative I have considered is checking the Kasm source code to see how they use rootless dind (if they do indeed use rootless access). Haven't gotten around to this yet.
EDIT: I am converting my application to use the Docker API. Maybe someone can shed some light on this issue.

Do you actually need a DinD container at all (I'd expect it to be a fairly unusual setup)?  What is trying to interact with it?  Can it do it over TCP rather than a Unix socket?

I was hoping to separate the container's docker environment from the host. The application creates containers that basically serve reverse ssh tunnels. Was thinking it's better for security

I can do it over TCP, the app is nodejs based. It's just easier to run commands than it is to create API calls. Although understandably it is probably the better option.
